# Link workflow task to page with custom webpart

Tags: workflow

I am trying to put a URL on the workflow task, which will bring user to a page with a custom webpart page which will load the related list item's details. I will pass in the ItemID in the URL for the page to identify which item to load.

How do I get the ID of the related list item in such a scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I felt the explanation on the issue is pretty vague, so this answer is based on my understanding.
Associate a Workflow to it, which will provide you Current Item - ID.

[image]